# String values in | delimited field are getting split to the right in awk

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, awk

While reading the 2nd Column from the given file
I am facing issues while reading multiple columns using awk from the given file.
While reading column 2 the contents are shifting to the right.

```
/home/Binay/bin] 82#head -2 /data/xyz/serial/fep_xyz/temp/./xyz_reject_file_details_20180926194730.dat
309_body_mass_index_at_refresh.ABORT.2018-05-13.dat_SKIP_AT|Failed MBR_KEY Lookup|94
309_disease_management_member_activity_at_refresh.ABORT.2018-05-13.dat_SKIP_AT|Failed MBR_KEY Lookup|11575
/home/Binay/bin] 82#
```

Expected OutPut

```
/home/Binay/bin] 82#  cat /data/xyz/serial/fep_xyz/temp/./xyz_reject_file_details_20180926194730.dat | awk -F'|' ' {print $1,$2,$3} ' | while read abort_file abort_reason record_count                        <
> do
> echo ${abort_reason}
> done
Failed MBR_KEY Lookup
Failed MBR_KEY Lookup
/home/Binay/bin] 83#
```

But I am currently getting the output as

```
/home/Binay/bin] 82#  cat /data/xyz/serial/fep_xyz/temp/./xyz_reject_file_details_20180926194730.dat | awk -F'|' ' {print $1,$2,$3} ' | while read abort_file abort_reason record_count                        <
> do
> echo ${abort_reason}
> done
Failed
Failed
/home/Binay/bin] 83#
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while IFS='|' read -r abort_file abort_reason record_count; do echo ${abort_reason}; done < filename
```

Why not directly use Input Field Separator in while ?

Answer (score 1):

Your second field contains spaces. The effect of your initial awk script is basically to replace your field separators with spaces, so `$abort_reason` becomes *the second space separated word on the line*.  Observe:

```
$ cat y.dat
a_b_c|two words|123
one_two|more words|234

$ awk -F'|' '{print $1,$2,$3}' y.dat
a_b_c two words 123
one_two more words 234

$ awk -F'|' '{print $1,$2,$3}' y.dat | while read a b c; do echo "$b"; done
two
more
```

versus using only bash, and populating an array for easier management:

```
$ while IFS='|' read -a a; do declare -p a; done < y.dat
declare -a a=([0]="a_b_c" [1]="two words" [2]="123")
declare -a a=([0]="one_two" [1]="more words" [2]="234")
```

If you really want to use awk for field splitting, you need to make sure that your output does not contain your field separator in the middle of a field. For example:

```
$ awk -F'|' '{gsub(/ /,"_"); print $1,$2,$3}' y.dat
a_b_c two_words 123
one_two more_words 234

$ awk -F'|' '{gsub(/ /,"_"); print $1,$2,$3}' y.dat | while read red green blue; do echo "$green"; done
two_words
more_words
```